# Saving xml nodes in R

Tags: r, xml, rvest

I am very new to scraping using R and xml, and I have a question about saving and loading the dataset.

I scraped a fairly large dataset using a code as follows

```
data<-list()
for(i in page[1:10]){
  pages<-read_html(paste0("http://www.gbig.org/buildings/", i))
  nodes<-html_nodes(pages, '.badge-info .cert-badge , .event , 
.date , .media-heading a , .truncated , .location , .buildings-type')
 data[[i]]  <-nodes
}
```

I thought I could save data and load it again for future using

```
save(data, file="trials.RData")
```

when I load it and try to use it again, I get a certain error message. What have I done wrong? and what would be the best way to save and load xml nodes?

```
{xml_nodeset (10)}
Error in node_write_character(x$node, options = options, encoding = encoding) : 
  external pointer is not valid
```

**EDIT**

My attempted load command is:

```
load("trials.RData")
```

Thank you

Comment: Yep. This is _technically_ a duplicate, but see the answer provided for both an alternate approach and one additional approach that uses the serialization alluded to in the dup'd answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason it isn't working is that nodes are an "xptr" or "external pointer" and they aren't serialized when they get saved to an R data file. The `xml2` package repository and various other places in R docs do have cautionary guidance for this, but nobody RTFM anymore. #sigh

One way to tackle your problem *and* stop yourself from DoSing the site again in the future is to extract the data from the nodes vs try to save the raw nodes *and* keep a copy of the source page so you can scrape that vs go back to the site and waste their bandwidth (again).

We'll need some packages:

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(tidyverse)
```

You should *always* start with checking out the site `robots.txt` and terms of service/terms and conditions. This site has a `robots.txt` but no ToS/T&C, so we'll see if they allow what you're trying to do:

```
robotstxt::get_robotstxt(urltools::domain("http://www.gbig.org/buildings/")) %>%
  cat()
## # See http://www.robotstxt.org/wc/norobots.html for documentation on how to use the robots.txt file
## #
## # To ban all spiders from the entire site uncomment the next two lines:
## # User-Agent: *
## # Disallow: /
## User-Agent: *
## Crawl-delay: 10
## Disallow: /beta_invites
## Disallow: /admin
## Disallow: /search
## Disallow: /green_schools
## Disallow: /api
## Disallow: /places/8194/activities
## Disallow: /places/935/activities
```

So, we need to use a 10s crawl delay between page requests and you better hope you didn't violate the techincal control by using the `/search` or `/api` paths to get that list of pages.

Also, we'll need this later since we're going to take an alternate approach to getting the nodes you want:

```
c(
  ".badge-info .cert-badge", ".event", ".date" , ".media-heading a",
  ".truncated", ".location" , ".buildings-type"
) -> target_nodes
```

And, we'll need to clean up ^^ later, too

```
clean_node_names <- function(x) {
  x <- tolower(x)
  x <- gsub("[[:punct:][:space:]]+", "_", x)
  x <- gsub("_+", "_", x)
  x <- gsub("(^_|_$)", "", x)
  x <- make.unique(x, sep = "_")
  x
}
```

For this example --- since you didn't provide any data --- we'll need some URLs so we'll grab the first 12 from this page:

```
pg <- read_html("http://www.gbig.org/buildings/")

html_nodes(pg, "a.cell") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>%
  sprintf("http://www.gbig.org%s", .) -> building_urls
```

Now, setup a progress bar since a 10s delay between pages is going to make this seem slow. I realize you may be and many others will be unlikely to follow the `robots.txt` rules but that doesn't mean you shouldn't.

```
pb <- progress_estimated(length(building_urls))
```

Finally, iterate over those URLs and:

- pause
- read the page
- build a data frame by extracting the node text from each CSS selector path; they're uneven in length so we make them all `list()` columns
- save the character source of the HTML page

NOTE: you may be able to make a nicer data frame with more individual/deliberate node extraction than this smash-and-grab approach one.

```
map_df(building_urls, ~{

  pb$tick()$print()

  Sys.sleep(10)

  x <- read_html(.x)

  map(target_nodes, html_nodes, x=x) %>%
    map(html_text) %>%
    set_names(clean_node_names(target_nodes)) %>%
    map(~list(.x)) %>%
    as_data_frame() -> tmpdf

  tmpdf$src_html <- as.character(pg)

  tmpdf

}) -> xdf
```

And, after a bit of waiting:

```
glimpse(xdf)
## Observations: 12
## Variables: 8
## $ badge_info_cert_badge <list> [<"Case Study", "Case Study", "Case Stu...
## $ event                 <list> [<"Whole Building Design Guide Case Stu...
## $ date                  <list> [<"06/20/2014", "08/13/2013", "08/13/20...
## $ media_heading_a       <list> [<"The Mutual Building  Christman Compa...
## $ truncated             <list> ["\nThe Christman Building LEED-EB, The...
## $ location              <list> ["208 N Capitol Ave, Lansing, MI, USA",...
## $ buildings_type        <list> ["\n\nThe Christman Building\n", "\n\nS...
## $ src_html              <chr> "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<h...
```

Because we store `src_html` you can process *that* with `read_html()` if you do need to get more/different info from each building.

NOTE: There is [an alternate method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070577/write-xml-object-to-disk) using `xml2::xml_serialize()`:

```
pb <- progress_estimated(length(building_urls))

map(building_urls, ~{

  pb$tick()$print()

  Sys.sleep(10)

  read_html(.x) %>%
    html_nodes(
      '.badge-info .cert-badge , .event , .date , .media-heading a , .truncated , .location , .buildings-type'
    ) %>%
    xml_serialize(NULL) -> nodes

  nodes

}) -> bldg_lst
```

Now, it's a list of raw vectors:

```
str(bldg_lst)
## List of 12
##  $ : raw [1:4273] 58 0a 00 00 ...
##  $ : raw [1:4027] 58 0a 00 00 ...
##  $ : raw [1:3164] 58 0a 00 00 ...
##  $ : raw [1:7718] 58 0a 00 00 ...
##  $ : raw [1:2996] 58 0a 00 00 ...
##  $ : raw [1:2908] 58 0a 00 00 ...
##  $ : raw [1:4506] 58 0a 00 00 ...
##  $ : raw [1:4127] 58 0a 00 00 ...
##  $ : raw [1:2982] 58 0a 00 00 ...
##  $ : raw [1:3034] 58 0a 00 00 ...
##  $ : raw [1:1800] 58 0a 00 00 ...
##  $ : raw [1:1877] 58 0a 00 00 ...
```

That you can save out.

When read back in, you would do:

```
map(bldg_lst, xml_unserialize)
## [[1]]
## {xml_nodeset (65)}
##  [1] <h2 class="buildings-page-title buildings-type"><img alt="Building" ...
##  [2] <p class="location">208 N Capitol Ave, Lansing, MI, USA</p>
## ...
## 
## [[2]]
## {xml_nodeset (62)}
##  [1] <h2 class="buildings-page-title buildings-type"><img alt="Building" ...
##  [2] <p class="location">3825 Wisconsin Ave NW, Washington, DC, USA</p>
## ...
## 
## [[3]]
## {xml_nodeset (54)}
##  [1] <h2 class="buildings-page-title buildings-type"><img alt="Building" ...
##  [2] <p class="location"> San Francisco, CA, USA</p>
## ...
## 
## [[4]]
## {xml_nodeset (127)}
##  [1] <h2 class="buildings-page-title buildings-type"><img alt="Building" ...
##  [2] <p class="location"> Washington, DC, USA</p>
## ...
## 
## [[5]]
## {xml_nodeset (50)}
##  [1] <h2 class="buildings-page-title buildings-type"><img alt="Building" ...
##  [2] <p class="location">4940 N 118th St, Omaha, NE, USA</p>
## ...
## 
## [[6]]
## {xml_nodeset (47)}
##  [1] <h2 class="buildings-page-title buildings-type"><img alt="Building" ...
##  [2] <p class="location"> Dallas, TX, USA</p>
## ...
## 
### (etc)
```

I still think the first suggested method is better.

Comment: Thanks for the unnecessary public service announcement mom!