# How to save and restore list of XML documents

Tags: r, xml2

I **scraped** several HTML files from the Internet Archive (Wayback Machine). To process these files I need time and do not want to strain the Internet Archive server the following days. So I want to store these HTML documents in a list, save it to a file and restore these (list)data later.

But when I try to open/view the restored file, I got the error message:

> Error in fun(x$node, ...) : external pointer is not valid

I have used the following code:

```r
library(xml2)
l = list()
l[[1]] <- read_html("<p>Hi!</p>")
l[[2]] <- read_html("<p>Hello</p>")
tmp <- tempfile()
saveRDS(l, tmp)
x <- readRDS(tmp)
```

I looked also into the following code but received the same error message when I tried to view/open content of the retored list.

```
tmp <- tempfile(fileext = ".RData")
save(l, file = tmp )
load(tmp, globalenv())
```

I tried also `write_html(l, tmp)` but here I received the error message:

> Error in UseMethod("write_html") :
> no applicable method for 'write_html' applied to an object of class "list"

Maybe to store the HTML documents in a list is not a good idea? But what other strategies would succeed in saving and restoring?

<sup>Created on 2019-08-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Session info

```r
devtools::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
#>  os       macOS Mojave 10.14.6        
#>  system   x86_64, darwin15.6.0        
#>  ui       X11                         
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
#>  ctype    en_US.UTF-8                 
#>  tz       Europe/Vienna               
#>  date     2019-08-05                  
#> 
#> ─ Packages ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package     * version date       lib source        
#>  assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  backports     1.1.4   2019-04-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  callr         3.3.1   2019-07-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  cli           1.1.0   2019-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  crayon        1.3.4   2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  desc          1.2.0   2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  devtools      2.1.0   2019-07-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  digest        0.6.20  2019-07-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  evaluate      0.14    2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  fs            1.3.1   2019-05-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  glue          1.3.1   2019-03-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  highr         0.8     2019-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  htmltools     0.3.6   2017-04-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  knitr         1.23    2019-05-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  magrittr      1.5     2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  memoise       1.1.0   2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  pkgbuild      1.0.3   2019-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  pkgload       1.0.2   2018-10-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  prettyunits   1.0.2   2015-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  processx      3.4.1   2019-07-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  ps            1.3.0   2018-12-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  R6            2.4.0   2019-02-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  Rcpp          1.0.2   2019-07-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  remotes       2.1.0   2019-06-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  rlang         0.4.0   2019-06-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  rmarkdown     1.14    2019-07-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  rprojroot     1.3-2   2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  stringi       1.4.3   2019-03-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  stringr       1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  testthat      2.2.1   2019-07-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  usethis       1.5.1   2019-07-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  withr         2.1.2   2018-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  xfun          0.8     2019-06-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  xml2        * 1.2.1   2019-07-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#>  yaml          2.2.0   2018-07-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
#> 
#> [1] /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070577/write-xml-object-to-disk might be useful