# How to correctly store a list of html files for web scraping?

Tags: r, xml, list, web-scraping, rvest

Using the rvest package, I've scraped information of cooking recipes from
https://minimalistbaker.com (e.g. title, number of comments, average rating, cooking time, etc.) and everything works well.

The problem however is to store the list object which contains the recipe pages and reload them again into R later (to avoid spamming the page again with requests)

When saving the recipes_html object (see example code below)
e.g. as .rds file, and reloading it later, I will receive the following error:

```
 recipes_html
"Error in doc_is_html(x$doc) : external pointer is not valid"
```

while it should be

```
 recipes_html[[1]]
{html_document}
<html lang="en-US">
[1] <head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; 
charset=UTF-8">\n<meta charset="UTF-8">\n<script type="tex ...
[2] <body class="post-template-default single single-post postid-42142 
single-format-standard woocommerce-no-js header-ful ...
```

Looking for a solution I came across
https://github.com/tidyverse/rvest/issues/181#issuecomment-395064636
or this
[Write xml-object to disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070577/write-xml-object-to-disk)

However, functions like xml2::write_html()
will return an error as my object recipes_html is a list

```
 Error in UseMethod("write_html") : 
 no applicable method for 'write_html' applied to an object of class "list"

class(recipes_html)
[1] "list"
class(recipes_html[[1]])
[1] "xml_document" "xml_node"
```

So, what would be an applicable method to store the recipes_html list object, so that I could later simply reload it and proceed with **scraping**?
Preferable without splitting up the list and storing each page individually
(as the function I built to extract the information in the subsequent steps, loops over the list of pages, which works very well.)

```
 #Reproducible code
 library(rvest)

example_links<-read_html("https://minimalistbaker.com/recipe-index/")%>%html_nodes(".entry-title a")%>%html_attr("href")%>%head()

#nytnyt function to introduce random waiting time between each request
nytnyt<- function (periods= c(1, 2.5)){
   tictoc <-runif(1, periods[1], periods[2])
   cat(paste0(Sys.time()), "- Sleeping for ", round(tictoc, 2),
   "seconds\n")
   Sys.sleep(tictoc)
 }


recipes_html<-list()                            #save the list to 
  for (i in 1:length(example_links)) {
   recipes_html[[i]]<-read_html(example_links[i])
   print(i)
   nytnyt(periods = c(2, 4))                   #make R wait between 2 to 4 seconds between each request
} 


saveRDS(recipes_html, "example_recipes.rds")      
readRDS("example_recipes.rds")                     #saving and loading the object again won't work.
```

Comment: Why don't you parse your file and make a dataframe to store the info inside the scrapped data ?